# Why does the following code not compile?

Tags: c#, generics, types, compiler-errors

I can't understand why the following code doesn't compile:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    public interface ITestCondition<T> {
    }

    public class TestConditionBase<T>: ITestCondition<T> {
    }

    public class TestCondition<T>: TestConditionBase<T> {
    }

    public static class TestConditionExtension {
        public static V Foo<V, T>(this V condition) where V: ITestCondition<T> {
            return condition;
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            new TestCondition<int>().Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

It says it can't find "foo". But it works perfectly without the generic type.

Comment: @SonerGönül .Net C# 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V can be inferred but T cannot, and therefore the call to Foo must fail.

Why can T not be inferred?

When performing method type inference **C# never makes a type inference from a constraint**. Inferences are made by examining the relationship between *arguments* and their corresponding *formal parameter type*. Only *after* inference is complete do we check to see that the constraint is satisfied.

Comment: You are right. When i use T as an method argument and call them method for example with an int, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't manage to infer the types. Specify them explicitly:

```
new TestCondition<int>().Foo<TestCondition<int>, int>();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this as your extension method:

```
public static class TestConditionExtension
{
    public static ITestCondition<T> Foo<T>(this ITestCondition<T> condition)
    {
        return condition;
    }
}
```

Since V is always an ITestCondition, there is really no reason to make it more generic than that.

A quick rule of thumb I use when I consider using a generic argument is "Does it matter what type it is". In this case, the specific type J doesn't matter, just the parent type does. So don't use a generic, just use the parent type. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There is a Reason. When you want to return a more specific type then just the base interface. Important for Fluent interfaceing.

Comment: Ah, I see, so you want to return the same type as the input type. Then @ken2k is completely right.